# How can I import sinon into an ember-cli test?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, sinon, ember-cli-addons

I'm trying to use sinon in my ember-cli app and I can't figure out how to import it. I have an import statement in the spec:

```
import { sinon } from 'sinon';
```

and then I try to use sinon in a test:

```
it('finds the todo model', function () {
  var store = this.subject().store;
  var spy = sinon.spy(store, 'find');

  this.subject().model();

  expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
});
```

however, when I run `ember test` from the command line I get this error:

```
not ok 8 PhantomJS 1.9 - TestLoader Failures my-app/tests/unit/routes/application-test: could not be loaded
---
    message: >
        Could not find module `sinon` imported from `my-app/tests/unit/routes/application-test`
    stack: >
        Error: Could not find module `sinon` imported from `my-app/tests/unit/routes/application-test`
            at requireFrom (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:119)
            at reify (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:106)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:149
            at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:156
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:13918
    Log: >
...
```

The one thing I've noticed is that `ember-sinon` has a very light footprint in the `bower_components/` directory:

```
$ls bower_components/sinon/
index.js
```

I've tried changing the import line to `import { sinon } from 'sinon/index';` but that hasn't worked either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to ember-cli, bower and es6 modules so links to background on those pieces would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after RTFMing for litterally minutes, I found the answer right there in the [test assets](http://www.ember-cli.com/#test-assets) section of the ember-cli documentation.

The setup:

```
ember install ember-sinon
```

^ this will throw an error so I ran the generator by hand.

```
ember generate ember-sinon
```

Then, import sinon in the `Brocfile`:

```
var isProduction = EmberApp.env() === 'production';
if (!isProduction) {
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/sinon/index.js', {type: 'test'});
}
```

Now, you can use `sinon.stub/spy/mock` in your specs but you'll still get a jshint error about sinon not being defined. I fixed this by adding:

```
/* global sinon */
```

to the top of the spec. It looks like you should be able to declare this globally in the jshintrc file but I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: To get rid of the jshint error you have to add "sinon" to the predef array in the "tests/.jshintrc". Not the project wide ".jshintrc"!! Should look something like { "predef": [ "sinon" ] };

Comment: thanks @phlppn that was exactly the issue with jshint.